# Finding a minor matrix of a matrix with C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm developing an app will be used for calculating matrixes and I'm currently working on minor function and I need a minor matrix for that. So, I wrote the code shown below. It actually works without any error but there is an issue about 4x4 matrices. It changes the 4x1 and 4x2 values.

In this image, places of 9 and 10 are wrong. They are at each others place.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcraA.png)

Note: There isn't any problem about textboxes, it's about the array (matrix).

Here is my code. I could easily solve it by rechanging them with a few lines of code but I'm trying to learn C# and Visual Studio, so I want to find the problem in my algorithm.

```
minorMatrix = new int[rowA.Value - 1, colA.Value - 1];
int k = 0, l = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rowA.Value - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colA.Value - 1; j++)
    {
        if (i < row - 1) 
        {
            k = i; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            k = i + 1; 
        }

        if (j < col - 1) 
        {
            l = j; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            l = j + 1; 
        }

        minorMatrix[i, j] = matrixA[k, l];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to remove the *i*th row and *j*th column? This should do it:

```
int[,] A = new int[3, 3];  // Original matrix
int[,] M = new int[2, 2];  // Matrix with ith row and jth column removed
int i = 2, j = 1;  // 3rd row, 2nd column to remove
for (int Mi = 0; Mi < A.GetLength(0); Mi++)
    for (int Mj = 0; Mj < A.GetLength(1); Mj++)
        {
            int Ai = Mi, Aj = Mj;
            if (Mi >= i)
                Ai = Mi + 1;
            if (Mj >= j)
                Aj = Mj + 1;
            M[Mi, Mj] = A[Ai, Aj];
        }
```